# PKCS#8 Error from JSON wrapper with AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, pkcs#8

Is there a recommended mechanism to parse the JSON wrapper from a private key stored in AWS Secrets Manager?

In my use case, when executing the python script the output results in an error with the system authenticating to as its does not read the key in PKCS#8 format.

I couldn't find any definitive guidance from AWS docs, etc. is there a best practice to to configure on SM or through a JSON decoder/ jq? https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import base64
import json

client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

response = client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId='arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:<>' 
)
print(response)
```

```
{'ARN': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:<redacted>', 'Name': 'aws_sm_keypair', 'VersionId': '', 'SecretString': '-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\\-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----', 'VersionStages': ['AWSCURRENT'],}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-11 ~]$ readlink -f sm1.py
/home/ec2-user/sm1.py
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-11 ~]$ snowsql -a <account>.us-east-1.privatelink -u <user> --private-key-path /home/ec2-user/sm1.py
Failed to load private key: Private key provided is not in PKCS#8 format. Pleas use correct format.

Comment: The AWS CLI and Cloud9 IDE print the correct key output. 

When running the python file from the command line, it throws a region based error that is defined in the script